# Dropdown not working in microsoft IE and microsoft edge

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I am using [ui-select 0.13.2](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select) plugin. Here is [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/3npaRXNO7g64VG4uqfsL?p=preview) for the problem part.

```
<ui-select multiple autocomplete="off"  name="colorName" id="colorId" ng-model="selected.colors" ng-required="true">
        <ui-select-match placeholder="Select or search a color in the list...">{{$item.name}}<span class="style-color-block-temp" style='background-color:{{$item.colorHash}}'></span></ui-select-match>
        <ui-select-choices repeat="color in colors | filter:$select.search">
          {{color.name }} <span class="style-color-block" style='background-color:{{color.colorHash}}'></span>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

I have a drop down in it, which is working fine in firefox and google chrome.

[image]

But in IE and edge I am getting strange behaviour.
[image]

This browser is giving me autosuggestions, which is making my drop down weired.

Comment: It's the IE/Edge auto suggest mode. You should look to this article: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000604.htm

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to disable it. I want it to work same in other browsers also. @ADreNaLiNe-DJ

Comment: @afzalex Actually I am not able to see the correct ui in plunker aswell, would you correct your plunker or create a fiddle?

Comment: @afzalex So you can't get rid of this behavior. You can't set the `z-index` of the "browser autocomplete".

Comment: no. Becuase that suggestion is created by software (i.e. browser). So on the top of all layers it is showing auto suggestions. @ADreNaLiNe-DJ

Comment: @afzalex : Are you able to solve this problem?

Comment: No @ParagBhayani , The only method that I think I currently have is to just disable autosuggestion. Which I don't want.

Comment: Your plunker is not working properly in my chrom or FF aswell, would you update it so that it can work properly.. because of that I am not able to understand your question properly...